# Low cost feedthrough for an acrylic vacuum chamber

Tags: vacuum

I am currently building myself a "hobby" vacuum chamber from 1 inch tickness acrylic sheets (I am very aware that acrylic is not the proper material). Inner dimensions of the the chamber is 40x40x40mm. After a few simulations in Solidworks, safety factor and displacements seemed okay.

What I need is to feed 8 cables through the sheets. After a research, I couldn't find any airtight cable gland or any low cost vacuum feedthrough. What is your suggestion for a low cost feedthough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Liquid tight cable glans](https://www.heyco.com/Liquid_Tight_Cordgrips/product.cfm?product=Liquid-Tight-Cordgrips-Pre-Assembled&section=Liquid_Tight_Cordgrips) are cheap, and many manufacturers make them.  If you have a productive enough vacuum pump, it may be able to keep up with small air leakage through them.  You could also add grease inside the gland.

Comment: Some others - https://www.defender.com/category.jsp?id=2289996&path=-1|328|2289986

Answer (score 1):

A sparkplug is air tight and provides an electrical feedthru for very high voltages.

They're also threaded and taps for the thread are common.

Also they are cheap!

(The body of the plug is resistive  ( between about 40 $\Omega$ and 1 k$\Omega$) and sometimes inductive - check the specs)

Comment: Brilliant solution, I'll give it a try. Thank you.